# Galaxy Note 4 "boot loop"?

Tags: boot, samsung-galaxy-note-4, custom-roms

I'm guessing it's called boot loop from research over the past few hours.
I switch it on, it loads the logo and phone introduction screen, the screen goes dark, it resets and then repeats.
Charges fine, works without charger. I've tried lots from Google results like take out battery, soft and hard reset, recovery boot screen: clear cache, factory reset. I've even tried installing TWRP and rooting via odin which was successful, computer recognised it via USB. I then tried installing a custom ROM and gapps which was also successful but still have boot loop issue.

Possible water damage, if so what part will be faulty?

Comment: Have you tried to boot your device while connected to the charger?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the reply Robert, yes I have and got the same result.

Comment: How many seconds does each loop take? This allows us to guess how far your device gets it the boot process.

Comment: @Robert From fully switched off I power it on and it takes 15 seconds for the screen to come off logo and go blank, then a further 5 seconds for the first vibrate followed by a second vibrate and reset 1 second later (approx)

Comment: sounds like short circuit in power button. watch youtube how to disassemble and dry components with hairdryer. android in general does not boot on modified partitions like recovery, you need to disable dm-verity first

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, I will try this